# How to find area of ​a circle?

Tags: integration, area

I have the equation in polar coordinates:
$$r=\cos(\phi)-\sin(\phi)$$
I just moved to 
Cartesian coordinates and drew a graph:
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2$$
[image]

And now I should find the area of this circle using integral. What I need to do?Please help

Comment: What integral? Just integral over the area? Do you need to use Green's theorem?

Comment: You can use $A=\pi r^2$ if you have to use integral you can use it on $\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac12}^2-x^2}$ and multiply by $4$ because the area don't change when you move the circle

Comment: Yes, I`m sure it`s a circle
I should use definite integral.
But I get different results calculating πr2 and your integral,Holo

Comment: @PashaMinigun look at the 2 answer to the post, those are the 2 ways I suggested and they will give you the same result

Comment: @Holo boundaries of the integral are 0 and r?

Comment: @PashaMinigun yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to do the algebra to change the coordinate system, you might as well finish the job algebraically.

$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$

and $A = \pi r^2 \implies A = \frac {\pi}{2}$

other options.

$r = \cos \phi - \sin \phi\\
r = \sqrt 2 (\cos (\phi + \frac {\pi}{4}))$

let $\theta = \phi + \frac {\pi}{4}$

$r = \sqrt 2 \cos \theta$
Which you might recognize as a circle of radius $\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}$

Caculus in polar coordinates

$A = \int_a^{b} \frac 12 r^2 \ d\phi$

The tricky part, $r\ge 0$ so you must find limits for $\phi$ such that this is true.

$\cos\phi \ge \sin\phi\\
\phi \in [-\frac {3\pi}{4},\frac {\pi}{4}]$

$\int_{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac 12 (cos\phi - \sin\phi)^2\ d\phi\\
\int_{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac 12 (cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi - 2cos\phi\sin\phi)\ d\phi\\
\frac 12 (\phi + \frac 12 \sin^2 \phi)|_{-\frac{3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\\
\frac {\pi}{2}$

And finally integrate in Cartesian.

$(x-\frac {1}{2})^2 + (y+\frac {1}{2})^2 = \frac 12\\
y = \pm \sqrt {\frac 12 - (x-\frac {1}{2})^2} - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\\
\int_{\frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}}^{\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}} (\sqrt {\frac 12 - (x-\frac {1}{2})^2} - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}) - (-\sqrt {\frac 12 - (x-\frac {1}{2})^2} - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2})\ dx\\
\int_{\frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}}^{\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}} 2\sqrt {\frac 12 - (x-\frac {1}{2})^2}\ dx\\
x - \frac 12 = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \sin t\\dx = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\cos t\ dt\\
\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos^2 t\ dt\\
\frac 12 (t + \sin t\cos t)|_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\\
\frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thank you! It`s what I need

Answer (score 1):

lets take $$A=4\int_{0}^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way, because of the given parametrization of the circle: using Green's Theorem with the parametrization

$$\begin{align*}&r(t)=\left(\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos t\,,\,\,-\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin t\right)\,,\\
&r'(t)=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin t\,,\,\,\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos t\right)\end{align*}\;\;\;\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi$$

so:

$$A=\oint_C-y\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin t\right)\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin t\right)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\sin t+\frac12\sin^2t\right)dt$$

$$=\left.\frac1{2\sqrt2}\cos t\right|_0^{2\pi}+\left.\frac14\left(t-\cos t\sin t\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}=\frac\pi2$$